# Send mail with gmail in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, gmail, laravel-7

I'm trying to send mail with Gmail in laravel 7. **I get the result in localhost** but when I upload the project on the host I recieve this error and email not send:

```
local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection refused) at /home/wbrubkcom/libs/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269)
```

My env config for email is:

```html
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=myemailpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I searched in StackOverflow and test different ways such as useing Gmail app password or change port to 465 or change encryption to ssl but I don't get the result.

Comment: This may be a security feature for Gmail. It may not allow smtp access from an IP address if you have not logged in to their website from the same IP address. If you don't have an exceptionally good reason to send email from a gmail account I'd highly recommend using a different mail transport service like maligun or similar.

Comment: Also, depending on your host. Outgoing traffic on port 587 may be blocked by default

Comment: @OneSimpleGeek That's a good idea. I tried to use Mailchimp but it has limitations and I can't use premium account yet. So is there any limitations on mailgun?

Comment: I've used it on and off for a few years for multiple projects and haven't come across any limitations that have been a problem. If you're doing low volumes of mail it's free to try out and then really cheap after the trial.

Comment: Thanks, dear. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to

Manage google account->security->less secure app

and then allow it ..

may be that will resolve your issue.

Comment: then try using smtp